# Single use sign in url for azure ad?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to get a single use sign url that can be used by a browser client that would automatically authenticate the browser session and redirect to saml2 integrated resource? Currently I have a app integration (App A) setup using saml2 that uses azure ad as its identity provider. So any unauthenticated request to it gets redirected to the azure ad login page and then after it verifies the users credential submission it redirects to App A using SAML2.

I also have a web app (App B) that uses its own credential provider. I would like a subset of accounts in App B to get automatically authenticated using a special user setup in Azure Ad and then redirected to App A as that special user.

I configured a new App Integration in the Azure AD portal that gives me a client id and client secret. I can successfully use this in Postman to perform a Oauth2 /token request. The response includes a bearer token amd also some cookies are in the response. Problem is that if I try the same request using an ajax/xhr command I run into a CORs error and the browser never attempts the POST request. I understand it isn't wise to be passing the client secret to the client side script but that is the only API I saw that was trying to setup the cookies I think I need to make this work. I can use server side code to retrieve this access token and pass it to the client script but I dont think that is of any use. Unless there is someway I can use it to redirect the browser to the Azure AD login page itself using a special one time link that would siliently authenicate the token and setup the cookies into the browser session.

Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

That's client credentials flow that you are trying to use and is never intended for use from a front-end (public client). I'm also pretty sure it does not setup any useful cookies since it is service principal (app-only) authentication with no user involved.

And no, you cannot skip interactive authentication in any way to get a proper session cookie on Azure AD; the user has to log in.
You can specify the user account though by putting `login_hint=user@company.com` in the authorization URI.
Then the user only has to write their password (and go through MFA if that's on).
*If the user has an active session on Azure AD at this point, they'll be logged in silently.*

The main issue there is that in order to log in against Azure AD, the user has to log in against Azure AD :)
And basically you can't do it for them.
Okay, non-interactive authentication can be done with Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow (ROPC), but that only gives you tokens, it does not create a session cookie.
And it does not work if the user has MFA/is federated/password has expired etc.
Generally this flow should be avoided, and I don't think it is useful in your case, since app A would have to get the resulting token from this.
And you can't do this from front-end JS either :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is there anyway you can think that an App B user can get signed into Azure AD as a App A user non interactively?. Where App A is setup with SAML2 integration and App B uses its own credential store but has access to a client id and client secret setup in the same Azure AD?

Comment: I don't think so at least :(